# NullPointerException PrimeFacesContext.release Primefaces 5.0

Tags: primefaces, filter, nullpointerexception, jsf-2.2

So I'm trying to update a JSP project that my company has from PrimeFaces 4.0 to PrimeFaces 5.0, and I'm getting a `NullPointerException` from `org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)` when I don't implement my own Authorization Filter. When I do, it comes on the line `filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);`

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.LEGACY_WIDGET_NAMESPACE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--<context-param>-->
<!--<param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>-->
<!--<param-value>true</param-value>-->
<!--</context-param>-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

    <!-- <filter>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>web.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>-->
</web-app>
```

and my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
                version="2.1">
</faces-config>
```

and my AuthFilter.java, which causes the error when the last two servlet-mappings of my web.xml file are uncommented (and the contents of doFilter are un-commented):

```
package web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
//      if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
//          HttpServletRequest req = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
//          if (req.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/application/")) {
//              BusinessLayer bl = (BusinessLayer) req.getSession().getAttribute("businessLayer");
//              if (bl == null || bl.getClient() == null) {
//                  ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendRedirect("/login.html");
//              }
//          }
//      }
//      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

It should probably be noted here that the above code works fine un-commented with PrimeFaces 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was caused by the Maven download of PrimeFaces; downloading straight from their site and manually putting the .JAR into my WEB-INF/lib folder fixed everything. They really need to fix that.